# 2d NSArray with enumerated types in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, enums

I am creating a word search game with enumerated types for the cells. I need to create a 2 dimensional array, and to achieve this will code an `NSArray` of `NSArrays` holding objects of the enum type.

I looked at creating an array of enums, and did so. I am also capable of creating an `NSArray` of `NSArrays`. But creating an `NSArray` of `NSArrays` containing enumerated types dow not work how I'd expect it to:

**My `BoardCellState.h` class:**

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, BoardCellState) {
BoardCellStatePartOfWord = 0,
BoardCellStatePartOfWordSelected = 1,
BoardCellStateNotPartOfWord = 2,
BoardCellStateNotPartOfWordSelected = 3,};
```

**My `NSArray` (10x10 grid)**

```
NSArray *partofwordArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@[@(BoardCellStatePartOfWord),@(BoardCellStatePartOfWord),@(BoardCellStatePartOfWord),@(BoardCellStatePartOfWord),@(BoardCellStatePartOfWord),@(BoardCellStatePartOfWord),@(BoardCellStateNotPartOfWord),@(BoardCellStatePartOfWord),@(BoardCellStateNotPartOfWord),@(BoardCellStateNotPartOfWord)], nil],
            ...(repeated 9 more times)...nil];
```

Now accessing partofwordArray does not function as I expect

```
            int partofWordState = [partofwordArray [row][col] intValue];
```

results in unrecognised selector sent to call stack (intValue), where row and column are any integer between 0 and 9 (so within my grid)

My solution has been

```
id returnedID =partofwordArray[row][0];
            int partofWordState = [returnedID[col] intValue];
```

Where once again any row and column are between 0 and 9.

Although this works it is hacky and I can't explain why. The line that creates an error makes much more sense, so why does it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.you are creating three dimension array here..
With your array defined as above you can get values like

> int partofWordState = [partofwordArray [row][0][col] intValue];

It will work ..will not give any error.

for two dimension array you should define like following..

> NSArray *partofwordArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSArray
>   arrayWithObjects:@(BoardCellStatePartOfWord),@(BoardCellStatePartOfWord),@(BoardCellStatePartOfWord),@(BoardCellStatePartOfWord),@(BoardCellStatePartOfWord),@(BoardCellStatePartOfWord),@(BoardCellStateNotPartOfWord),@(BoardCellStatePartOfWord),@(BoardCellStateNotPartOfWord),@(BoardCellStateNotPartOfWord),
>   nil] ,
>    ....up to 9 ..

With this code you can actually access data the way you want.

> int partofWordState = [partofwordArray [row][col] intValue];

Comment: Good Luck! Happy coding!